# How to expand the "Overwrite ${file} (ynarxdeiH)" prompt automatically?

Tags: yeoman

When doing `this.fs.write` how can I expand the description of each letter automatically? (without having to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
? Overwrite my-super-file? (ynarxdeiH)
```

What is that yarnsomething?

Comment: To answer a question, post an answer. Don't put the answer in the question.

Comment: @RaymondChen I updated the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
y) overwrite
n) do not overwrite
a) overwrite this and all others
r) reload file (experimental)
x) abort
d) show the differences between the old and the new
e) edit file (experimental)
i) ignore, do not overwrite and remember (experimental)
h) Help, list all options
```